How to change print speed along a perimeter?
I have a rounded square geometry which I want to use for strength tests, see image.

Instead of printing it at the same speed everywhere, I would like each side to have a different speed so it's faster to test values.
I tried to apply a modifier, as shown, which changes speed only.

However Orca Slicer "cuts" the piece and does not continue with the same path it used before:

This is not what I want, and it would not allow my testing as I planned it, since the printing head has to come to a complete stop, instead of just reducing/increasing the speed as needed.
How can I keep the original tool path and only change speed in various sections of a model?
